# Microsoft Lync crashes on double clicking any user from the contacts list

Tags: lync

I applied couple of working certificates after a quick install (Lync). Soon-after logging Lync, I tried to message by double-clicking one of the users from my contacts list; suddenly, I face app crash that prompts me to restart the application. This continues after restarting the app.

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Date/Time: 2014-11-28 05:44:49 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Lync
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Lync
Application Signature: UCCP
Application Version: 14.0.10.141024
Crashed Module Name: unknown
Crashed Module Version: unknown
Crashed Module Offset: unknown
Blame Module Name: Microsoft Lync
Blame Module Version: 14.0.10.141024
Blame Module Offset: 0x02019556
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=English Loc=0x0409
Crashed thread: 0
```

Comment: Could you confirm the Lync Client version and your OS version which I suspect may be Lync 2011 and Mac OS respectably.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hot fix released for the Mac client to stop Lync crash when accessing various USB devices available from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2926055.

Comment: Thank you! let me try and get back to you. Cheers!!

Comment: Tried, but no luck :(